# Destroy one plugin within another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions, destroy

If you'd prefer to look at the working site where the problem exists see the Credentials section (I am animating the content beneath the blue colour block '#star'):

```
http://176.32.230.17/apptivation.co.uk/m/home/
```

I have two plugins

1. [:onscreen](http://benpickles.github.com/onScreen/) to play animations when a targeted DIV is visible on the viewport
2. [Full Screen Page Flip](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layout/) to make a book like effect between sections

Plugin two expects the following section structure on one page in order for it to work:

```
<div class="bb-item">
<div class="content">
    <div class="scroller">
                    <!-- this is the div i want to animate -->
        <div id="star" class="inner-pad">
            some content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I initialise onscreen plugin like so:

```
$(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
    $("#star").filter(":onScreen").addClass('animated bounceInRight');
 }, 0)                             
})
```

If the code above were the first section, my '#star' div would successfully add the classnames just the way onscreen (plugin 1) was intended. However if I were to move that code to the fifth section (for example), onscreen would add the classnames before I even get to (visibly see) that section. This is where I think plugin 2 is affecting plugin 1, making plugin 1 think that div is actually visible when it isn't.

How can I ensure that the onscreen plugin does its job and only adds classnames when I am ONLY in a particular section?

**I've tried** removing classnames 'animated bounceInRight' before the onscreen plugin is initialized but that didn't work. In [this script file](http://pastebin.com/UmyJ6zBW) (of plugin 2) it destroys some elements and reinitialises when the page turn is put in motion, could I do the same with onscreen? How might I do this?

Comment: Is there only 1 element with the id "star"?

Answer (score 0):

Most jQuery plugins store the new instance of their object within jQuery data. I took a peak at what I think is the royal slider code - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/ - and I think that you could destroy it by directly referencing the royalSlider object.

First you're going want to check and see if the element you're trying to call destroy on actually has a royalSlider instance.

[See this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094243/cant-get-the-destroy-method-of-a-jquery-ui-plugin-to-work-conflicting-jquer)